# filter the result by 'g / ml' using SQL

Tags: sql

I have the below table from which I need to filter which holds both "g / ml".

```
name            product
----------------------------------
Sunflower oil       pure 180g/200ml @Rs.20
groundnut oil       gold 300g @Rs.25
Olive oil       Filter 470g/500ml @Rs.30
coconut oil     Filter 1000ml @Rs.30
```

The below query gives me result as

```
select Name, product
from Logistic
where product like '%ml%'
```

```
name            product
----------------------------------
Sunflower oil       pure 180g/200ml @Rs.20
Olive oil       Filter 470g/500ml @Rs.30
coconut oil     Filter 1000ml @Rs.30
```

The expected result is

```
name            product
----------------------------------
Sunflower oil       pure 180g/200ml @Rs.20
Olive oil       Filter 470g/500ml @Rs.30
```

What I can apply in the where clause to get the expected results

Comment: `like '%g%/%ml%'`

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: What if you have an entry `500ml/150g`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `%g/%ml%`. The `%` can appear in any position in the matching pattern.